# perfmon same trace, different results?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, perfmon

I set up perfmon on the same server twice (by mistake). (with a one hour difference, and I let it run for some hours).

So I got the same trace twice…

I do not understand the results:
[image]

It is the exact same trace, but the maximum for Free list stalls/sec is 395 in one and 139 in the other… Why is that difference? Even in the graph I can’t see it…

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your polling interval was, but if it is more than one sec, like 10 or 15 sec, then most likely it is overlapping and you are capturing the value at different times that are seconds apart.